# How to setup my own dns VPN server?

Tags: xubuntu, dns, vpn

How to setup my own DNS VPN server on Ubuntu, such as YourFreedom DNS connection?

YourFreedom is using DNS port 53 for VPN. İs it possible to use in OpenVPN config file?

Comment: Have you tried to specify port 53 in your openvpn server config file? Generally you may hit performance limits on the port 53... If it is required I would set up only UDP service.

Comment: I guess openvpn doesnt support dns connection.I know dns connection choise isnt make sense.Its very importand for me.

Comment: if you think handle this.Contact me please onraydeniz2@gmail.com